# Google sign in not working after publishing in play store even using the json file for release apk

Tags: android, json, google-play-services

In my app I am having an option of google sign-in, it works fine in debug mode as well as in release mode. I have generated 2 SHA keys to get json file from google.One is through **debug.kestore** and another is from **release keystore**. I run my app 
by installing the release apk, it works perfectly but when I upload the same apk over playstore it does not work. Why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution, there is a new SHA key generated by playstore when you upload the app to play store, just copy and paste that SHA key into your app credentials of developer console as new SHA key.

Answer (score 0):

If you have opted in for "Google Play App Signing" while uploading the app in playstore . You should also add the SHA1 from "App signing" in Release management tab in playstore in your Firebase project.

you can read more about it [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en)